# Tracing a "freehand" region of interest

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm using MATLAB and have the image processing toolbox; what I would like to do is select an irregular region of an image, and then clear everything outside this region. I could use the roipoly function, but this would require me to click on numerous points when I'd prefer to trace around the image area I need. Is there a way or a function that would lend itself to this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apologies, I'm using MATLAB and have the image processing toolbox. I'll add to question now!

Comment: Did you look at the other ROI functions available in the image processing toolbox? Hint: one is called `imfreehand`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can use [imfreehand](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfreehand.html) which does what you are looking for.

You can then use its numerous methods to create a mask (with the createMask method) and then crop your image according to your mask.

Here is a very simple example.

```
clear
clc

A = imread('peppers.png');

figure, 

imshow(A);

hROI = imfreehand(gca); 

Position = getPosition(hROI);

BW = createMask(hROI);

figure;

subplot(1,2,1)

imshow(A);

subplot(1,2,2);

imshow(BW);
```

Comment: Your, sir / madam , are a hero. Thank you.

Comment: +1 - Didn't know about `imfreehand`... and here I was drawing my surfaces programmatically.  Sometimes this is just faster.  Thanks!

Comment: great then! That's the beauty of SO isn't it? :)